# Office.js Addin has stopped loading from local domain in Windows 10 Excel

Tags: javascript, excel, windows, office365, office-js

Excel Addin has stopped loading from local domain after Windows 10 update:

version:

[image]

Here is my manifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OfficeApp xsi:type="TaskPaneApp"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1">
    <Id>355038ef-5ca5-7223-8e13-d5e622c6a577</Id>
    <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
    <ProviderName>Comapny LLC</ProviderName>
    <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>

    <DisplayName DefaultValue="ExcelAddin DEV"/>
    <Description DefaultValue="Import and export data from salesforce.com CRM"/>

    <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://exceladdin.local/assets/images/favicon.png"/>
    <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://exceladdin.local/index.php/about-us" />

    <Hosts>
        <Host Name="Workbook"/>
    </Hosts>

    <Requirements>
        <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
            <Set Name="ExcelApi" MinVersion="1.1"/>
            <Set Name="IdentityAPI"/>
        </Sets>
    </Requirements>

    <DefaultSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://exceladdin.local"/>
    </DefaultSettings>
    <Permissions>ReadWriteDocument</Permissions>
</OfficeApp>
```

Tats what I see in Excel ribbon:

[image]

Comment: Please add some details. Did the add-in ever load? Did changes in the manifest create the problem?

Comment: Have you tried looking into the [Event Log](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_Viewer)?

Comment: @RickKirkham Ever loads ok, no changes in manifest

Comment: @AlexK What's your Windows 10 version including Edition, Version, and OS build? You can find it by going to Settings > System > About. Also, can you try doing a Repair on your Office installation?

Comment: @RickKirkham Windows 10 home, versin 1709, Build 16299.192, I tried to repair and reinstall, but not working

Comment: @UweKeim thats what i saw in source "Mincrosoft Office 16 Alert" of event log: New Office Add-in
This add-in comes from the Office Store. If you trust it, it will have access to the contents of any documents where this add-in is included. See more.
P1: Apps for Office
P2: 16.0.4266.1001
P3: 0x80042FAC
P4:

Comment: The event log message is about an add-in you got from the Office Store, not the add-in that you are developing. Could you uninstall any add-ins you got from the Office Store and see if that has an effect?